# Interpreting total cost variable in QNEAT 3 OD Matrix using QGIS

Tags: qgis, table

I am using QGIS 3.16.

The Matrix itself is optimised for Travel Time using pre-defined speed-limits on roads (These are ok, I have checked them). However, the total cost output is in the thousands (i.e., 2896) for some journeys, which makes no sense (if the results are to be interpreted in minutes) because the maximum distance away from the destination points is already 1 hour (a layer generated via ORS plug-in).

How should I interpret these variables, if not in minutes?

Comment: What about Seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QNEAT3 fastest path optimization strategy uses a speed field with speed values which are in kilometers per hour (km/h). Using this speed field the output cost in the OD matrix is in seconds. This is the reason for the high values.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I thought the measure being in seconds was odd but how you explain it makes perfect sense.